# Android sending ViewHolder from myAdapter for RecyclerView to Activity gives null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Client activity with Recyclerview of Clients from sqlite. It looks like:

```
 public class KlientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KlientAdapter.ViewHolder> {  
      private Cursor cursor;
      ViewHolder staryHolder;  

      public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {      
        public TextView TextViewImie;
        public TextView TextViewNazwisko;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
          super(v);
          TextViewImie = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewImie);
          TextViewNazwisko = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNazwisko);

        }
      }  
     public KlientAdapter(Cursor c) {
       cursor = c;
     }
     public Cursor getCursor(){
          return cursor;
     }
     public ViewHolder getHolder(){
          return staryHolder;
     }
      @Override
      public KlientAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
          int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_klienci, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
      }
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {       
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);    
        holder.TextViewImie.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        holder.TextViewImie.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        holder.TextViewNazwisko.setText(cursor.getString(2));       

        holder.TextViewImie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    rowKlik(holder,position);
                }
            });
        holder.TextViewNazwisko.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rowKlik(holder,position);
            }
        });    
      }
      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return cursor.getCount();
      }
      public void rowKlik(ViewHolder holder, int p){      
          if(staryHolder != null){    
              staryHolder.TextViewImie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
              staryHolder.TextViewImie.setSelected(false);
              staryHolder.TextViewNazwisko.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
              staryHolder.TextViewNazwisko.setSelected(false);
          }
         holder.TextViewImie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_pressed);
         holder.TextViewImie.setSelected(true);
         holder.TextViewNazwisko.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_pressed);
         holder.TextViewNazwisko.setSelected(true);
         staryHolder = holder;              
      }
    }
```

than in my ClientActivity (ka is my KlientAdapter) I have:

```
public void DetaleStart(View view){
            ViewHolder vh = ka.getHolder();         
            if(vh != null){                 
                if(vh.TextViewEmail.isSelected()){
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    prefs.edit().putInt("Id", vh.TextViewImie.getId()).commit();                        
                    prefs.edit().putString("imie", vh.TextViewImie.getText().toString()).commit();
                    prefs.edit().putString("nazwisko", vh.TextViewNazwisko.getText().toString()).commit();          
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetaleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);                       
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WYBIERZ KLIENTA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WYBIERZ KLIENTA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

It works fine. In my DetailActivity I have also RecyclerView and I use Detail Adapter (basically this same - just different data from my db). It change background resource correctly, but when I try to use from my DetailActivity

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = DetailAdapter.getHolder();
```

it give me null (but when I use Log to get information about holder in rowKlick method it's not null) so I can't edit details for Klient. I have no idea where the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to design observer design pattern where you have to set onClicklistener in ViewHolder and when a click is done on any cell , your listener will catch data from viewholder and pass to your activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot I add observer and everything works perfect. Now, I try to figure out how it is possible that it works fine in my ClientActivity without observer. The only difference is that CliectActivity is my MainActivity...

Comment: BDZ, did you facing any issue related to observer?  You are using best practices to achieve desired functionality.